# Capture response from webhooks

Tags: php, webhooks

Is there a simple script that will capture POSTs from webhooks and save them to a DB, just like PostBin?

Thanks,
B.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty simple to whip one up yourself. Below is some pseudo code.

Database:

```
PostTable
    key varchar(32)
    value text
    date_created timestamp
```

PHP

```
foreach $_POST as key, value
    query = "insert into PostTable values(key, value, now())
    execute query
```

This will track all the incoming post requests and store it in the database along with the time of the request.

You can also add additional data such as referrer, cookie data etc.

Make sure to take care of security in case you are exposing this URL publicly.

Good luck!